# Calling a function directly vs using the apply/call method

Tags: javascript

In the following code to generate a `not` function:

```js
function not(func) {
    return (...args) => !func(...args);
}

const even = x => x%2 === 0;
const odd = not(even);


let a = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(a, a.map(odd));
```

Is there any reason to use `func(...args)` vs `func.call(this, ...args)`? What might be a use case where the second would be a better option than the first (if ever)? And finally, is `func.bind(this)(...args)` the same as `func.call(this, ...args)`?

Another example would be the difference between the two ways of invoking it:

```js
function compose(f, g) {
    return function(...args) {
        return f(g(...args));                       // first
        return f.call(this, g.apply(this, args));   // second
        return f.bind(this)(g.bind(this)(...args)); // third

    }
}
console.log(compose(x=>x*x, (x,y)=>x+y)(2,3));
```

Obviously the first one would be preferred if they're all essentially the same.

Comment: have you tried the other methods to call the function?

Comment: @NinaScholz could you please clarify? Yes I tried all the versions I mentioned in the question but couldn't find any differences.

Comment: Are you asking if there’s *ever* a difference between `func(...args)` and `func.call(this, ...args)`, or just in the specific case of functions that don’t use `this`, like `even`? If it’s the former, did you look up the documentation for `call`? If it’s the latter, do you have reason to expect that there is one?

Comment: For your smoke tests there is no difference, it is a difference in real world applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `not` is using arrow notation to return its new function, if it contained the `this` keyword its value would be whatever `this` is when `not` is called, rather than whatever `this` is when the returned function is called.

The value of `this` could be conserved if `not` avoids using arrow notation, because functions created by [arrow notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) don't have their own `this` or `arguments`:

```
function not(func) {
    return function (...args) {
        return !func.apply(this, args);
    }
}
```

Avoiding arrow notation also means you could pass through `arguments` directly instead of using a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to gather them as an `Array`:

```
function not(func) {
    return function () {
        return !func.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```

Maintaining the value of `this` is only important if you expect your `not` function might be applied to functions that care about their `this` value. But it's quite easy to maintain, and unless your use case requires something different there should be no harm in passing it through like this.

---

To answer your second question, no `func.bind(this)(...args)` is not *quite* the same as `func.call(this, ...args)`. Though the difference doesn't really matter so much if you're not saving the function returned by `func.bind(this)`.

[Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) creates a new version of a function which *always* has the same value for `this` regardless of how that function is invoked. [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), on the other hand, only invokes a function in a particular way, it doesn't also create a new version of it first.

Answer (score 1):

It makes a difference, if you use a prototype from a method like [`Set#has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has).

In this case `this` has to be preserved for the call, or better with `apply`, because of having an array of arguments.

```js
function not(func) {
    return function(...args) { return !func.apply(this, args); };
    //              or with spreading !func.call(this, ...args);
}

const hasNot = not(Set.prototype.has);

let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(a.map(hasNot, new Set([1, 2, 3])));
```